# view the sql_fulltext[clob] using v$sql?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, clob

I'm using **select sql_text from v$sql** to view the currently running query in my aplication. It shows only 4000 chars of running query. So that I used the following,

> **select sql_fulltext from v$sql**

But it showing only as clob. How can I view the whole query in this case in oracle?

Comment: To work with CLOB's and other large objects you should use the functions in the DBMS_LOB package.  Documentation for the DBMS_LOB package may be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lob.htm).

Answer (score 1):

sqlplus has not problems showing CLOB contents, just make sure to ..

```
set long 2000000
```

so some such high number > the max size of your CLOB, before running the query.